# How does cancer of the larynx (laryngeal cancer) affect the respiratory system?

Tags: human-biology, cancer, systems-biology

The larynx is part of the respiratory system and is responsible for producing sound (our voices). My question is how cancer in the larynx (voice box) affect the respiratory system overall? I appreciate any answer, but if it's not too inconvenient, please don't use too complex terminology (I'm in grade 10 Canada).

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Bio@SE. What kind of googling have you done on topic? More precisely, what kind of information you want to get on that topic? Please, be advised that this site has policy on [what questions are appropriate](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Currently your question is too broad + you didn't provide any background or effort of your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this website:

http://www.spirometry.guru/fvc.html

it causes difficulty with inhalation but exhalation is normal...

> "Typically the expiratory part of the F/V-loop is normal: the
>   obstruction is pushed outwards by the force of the expiration."
>   "During inspiration the obstruction is sucked into the trachea with
>   partial obstruction and flattening of the inspiratory part of the
>   flow-volume loop."

the exact symptoms of a laryngeal tumor depends on where it is located on the larynx... above the vocal cords, on the vocal cords, or below the vocal cords...

but more generally:

**anatomy:** 
*mouth/nose-->pharynx-->larynx-->trachea-->bronchi-->lungs*

a tracheostomy may be necessary... basically the surgeon makes a connection between the skin outside the throat and the trachea... this bypasses the larynx (as well as pharynx and nose/mouth)...